# Containerized Django application works on local, but not on GKE

Tags: django, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

Any containerized Django applications work in local, but only return "`no healthy upstream`" when run on GKE.

I tried with this django example: https://github.com/mukulmantosh/cloud-code-helloworld
on which I only commented out the `mysqlclient` in the `requirements.txt` file. I also only use the content in the `src/` folder.

In GKE the application runs behind an ingress internal load balancer (I have no access to Cloud Run for some corporate reason).

What I get in local mode:

```
(base) C:\Users\path\to\app>docker run -p 8080:8080 helloworld:1
[21/Feb/2024 10:54:17] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3968
[21/Feb/2024 10:54:17] "GET /static/KE-hello-world.svg HTTP/1.1" 200 116030
[21/Feb/2024 10:54:17] "GET /static/cloud_bg.svg HTTP/1.1" 200 7213
[21/Feb/2024 10:54:17] "GET /static/kubernetes-engine-icon.png HTTP/1.1" 200 6967
[21/Feb/2024 10:54:19] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3968
```

What I get in the Workload logs on GCP:

```
2024-02-21 12:03:40.613 CET
Not Found: /
2024-02-21 12:03:40.613 CET
[21/Feb/2024 11:03:40] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 2272
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a VPC firewall rule that allows the load balancer health check probe IP ranges to connect to the kubernetes nodes running your deployment.
Per https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/health-check-concepts#ip-ranges for internal load balancers they are:

```
35.191.0.0/16
130.211.0.0/22
```